# java stream is closed

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to use stream getfirst method two times but an error occurred says (java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed) and this stream code begins at comment named here.

```
                //code
                Stream<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> sorted =
                        map.entrySet().stream()
                           .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
                
                Supplier<Stream<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>>  sort2 = () -> sorted;
                Optional<String> kk = Optional.of(sort2.get().findFirst().get().getKey());
                Optional<Integer> vv = Optional.of(sort2.get().findFirst().get().getValue());
                int vmax = vv.get().intValue() ;    
                int count=0;
                ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>() ;
                for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> h: map.entrySet() ) {
                    if(h.getValue()==vmax) {
                        a.add(h.getKey()) ;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                
                if(count>1) {
                    Collections.sort(a);
                    System.out.println(a.get(0));
                    
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(kk.get());
                }    
                map.clear();
    
            }       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort2` is not doing anything for you, and simply hiding the issue that you can't reuse `sorted`.

In this situation, by far the best solution is to store `sorted.findFirst()` in a variable and reuse it rather than call `findFirst()` twice.  If you wanted to do it like this, then you would have to write

```
Supplier<Stream<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>> sort2 = () ->  map.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
```

...which would sort the entries twice, which would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a stream twice. Create a variable to hold the value of `findFirst()`

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.findFirst` is a *terminal operation* - calling `findFirst` twice on the same stream like you are doing is not possible.

It looks like you don't need to call it twice: even if you restarted a new stream, both times you would expect to get the same map entry. So call `findFirst` only once, and use the Optional it returns to you:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> firstEntry = sorted.findFirst();
Optional<String> kk = firstEntry.map(Map.Entry::getKey);
Optional<Integer> vv = firstEntry.map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Note that there's a better way to get the maximum item from the stream than sorting: using the `max` operator.

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```